# Taylor Series C++ another value

Tags: c++, series, taylor-series

I have to write program which calculates value cos(x) with use Taylor Series. for a= -7 to 7 program work.
problem is when i use value a>7 and the same a<-7.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


unsigned long long silnia(int n)
{
    unsigned long long a = 1;
    while(n)
        a *= n--;
    return a;
}
void taylor(int x)
{
    long double suma=0;
    for (int n=0; n<=10; n++)
    {
        suma+=pow(-1,n)*(pow(x,2*n)/silnia(2*n));
        cout << pow(-1,n) << " * " << pow(x,2*n) <<" / " << silnia(2*n) << " = " << pow(-1,n)*(pow(x,2*n)/silnia(2*n))<<endl;
    }
    cout << "taylor: "<<suma<< endl;
}

int main() {
    int a=5;
   taylor(a);
    cout << "cos: " << cos(a);
}
```

output onli taylor and cos for a=5:

```
taylor: 0.283664
cos: 0.283662
```

output for a = 9

```
1 * 1 / 1 = 1
-1 * 81 / 2 = -40.5
1 * 6561 / 24 = 273.375
-1 * 531441 / 720 = -738.112
1 * 4.30467e+007 / 40320 = 1067.63
-1 * 3.48678e+009 / 3628800 = -960.864
1 * 2.8243e+011 / 479001600 = 589.621
-1 * 2.28768e+013 / 87178291200 = -262.414
1 * 1.85302e+015 / 20922789888000 = 88.5647
-1 * 1.50095e+017 / 6402373705728000 = -23.4436
1 * 1.21577e+019 / 2432902008176640000 = 4.99719
taylor: -0.149111
cos: -0.91113
```

sorry for my bad english and thanks for help!

Comment: I recommend against using the `pow` function for integer powers. And for alternating `-1` and `1` integers, there are simpler ways to do that than using `pow` (like a plain `int` variable initialized to `1`, then multiply by the integer value `-1` each iteration of your loop).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What u recomed for recommend for pow(x,2*n)? for 1 and -1 i do:  ```code q=1 ``` and on teh end loop ```code q*=-1``` and effect is the same

Comment: With only 10 iterations the factorial divisor (`silnia(2*n)`) has not yet overpowered the denominator.  Increasing the number of iterations to 20 causes the factorial to overflow `unsigned long long`, changing `silnia` to use `long double` and using 20 iterations gets the series to converge - live - https://godbolt.org/z/7KaYzjhKG

Comment: A simple `for` loop, iterating `2 * n` times, and multiplying `x` by itself (`result = x; for (unsigned i = 0; i < 2 * n; ++i) { result *= x; }` or similar, but more generic and in its own function).

Comment: With `a = 9;` that is greater than `2π` so it should be reduced (e..g `fmod()`) to be within `0-2π`. So `9` radians is approx `2.717` radians (or about `155` deg.)

Answer (score 1):

Taylor series are mean to approximate a function around a specific pivot (most commonly 0). But, as you go further from that pivot, the approximation becomes more and more wrong.
Here is a plot, generated by Wolfram alpha, which shows `cos(x)` and Tailor Series approximation that function at varying degrees(=highest exponent of derivative):
[image]

As you can see, the best approximation(10th degree) is only close for values up to ~±6. If you want values that are closer to the true values, you will have to increase your steps or change your pivot!

To learn more about Tailor Series you can do some more research or watch this [intuitive video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3d6DsjIBzJ4) by 3b1b.

Comment: saying "increase steps" you mean increase steps in loop like this for(int n=0; n<20; n++)? and whay you mean saing change my pivot? for example x=9 than a use function with x=0.9?

Comment: Yes but but be careful as factorial 40 ( `silnia(2*n)` ) will overflow `unsigned long long`

Comment: @RichardCritten ok, thanks! For exercise it work but how can I change my pivot ? cause it work, good, but when use x=90 is to big even for long double.

Comment: @malinowynosek_ well, changing your pivot would be "cheating", of sorts. Instead of approximating the function `cos(x)`, you'd approximate `cos(x - 90)`. That way the approximation is most precise at x=90, but is less precise at x=0. (The reason I say that this is cheating is because your value at x=90 would be set by "the 0th derivative" of cos(x). In other words you are simply calculating `cos(90)`, which takes away the point of using an approximation in the first place). I believe this is better explained in the video I linked.

Comment: @malinowynosek_ if you rearrange the formula you can do division before multiplications ie choosing small numbers for ease of expression - `(5*5*5*5)/5!` == `(5/5)*(5/4)*(5/3)*(5/2)*(1/5)` note the (1/5) on the end you have as many of these are you have unmatched factorial divisors.  Algebraically `(a*b)/(c*d) == (a/c)*(b/d)`